# Django Template Tags and Meta-Programming: Is there any way of modifying a variable's name before calling its context?

Tags: django, django-templates, metaprogramming

Suppose in views.py I have a variable (i.e., changing) number of forms or types of objects in my context. (I'll just use the word 'forms' for simplicity).

```
context = {
     'form_0': form_0,
     'form_1': form_1,
     'form_2': form_2,
     'form_3': form_3,
     # ... and so forth
}
```

Let's suppose that I have no way of knowing how many forms are in my context at any given time. Is it at all possible to do the following with template tags:

```
{% for i in (number of forms in context) %}

{{ form_i }} <-- where i is equal to the number i in the loop -->

{% endfor %}
```

Here the end result would translate to:

```
{{ form_0 }}
{{ form_1 }}
{{ form_2 }}
... and so forth
```

I'm doubtful that this is at all possible, but if it is, I would find it quite helpful.

Comment: Please don't do that, calling by name is really asking for trouble. Use a list instead.

Comment: Do you know of any user-friendly resources that show how I could accomplish this with a list? I'm a bit new to django template tags and django in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing by name, as in constructing a string that contains the name, is usually considered an *unsafe* approach: it can be harder than one thinks to make an algorithm that constructs the name correctly. Forthermore say that you do that and later remove `form_3`, then your algorithm will likely stop at `2`, but perhaps there are still other forms there, but you forgot about the algorithm fetching the forms.

It is better here to pass a *collection* of objects, for example a *list*:

```
context = {
    'forms': [form_0, form_1, form_2, form_3]
}
```

then we can render this in the template with:

```
{% for form_i in forms %}
    {{ form_i }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you thus add an extra form to the list, then that form will be part of the iterations in the template, and thus Django will render that form (or whatever you put in the list).

If you need acces to some specific forms as well, you can pass then trhough another name as well, for example:

```
context = {
    'forms': [form_0, form_1, form_2, form_3],
    # if we need specific items of form_2 in the template,
    # we can pass it under a specific name as well
    'form_2': form_2
}
```

so now we can both enumerate over the `forms` to render these, but if `form_2` has some interesting data we need to handle in the template as well, we can still use `{{ form_2.non_field_errors }}` for example.